# change font size in web view in uwp

Tags: uwp

I am currently working on UWP project and I use a web view to show html content.I want content in the project to be responsive to the screen sizes.Therefore I need to give different font sizes to web view in laptop size screen and PC screen.Following code is the one that I used to show content in PC screen

```
<StackPanel  x:Name="questionItem" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"   >
   <WebView Name="webview" Width="750"   util:WebViewCustomProperties.HtmlString="{Binding CourseName}"  ScriptNotify="WebViewT_ScriptNotify" DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"  />
</StackPanel>
```

in behind the code file,

```
 if (courseid != null)
        {
            course.CourseName = "<div style=\"font-size: 25px;VerticalAlignment:Center;font-family:Segoe UI;width: 100%;\">" + course.CourseName + "</div>";
        }
```

I gave different widths to the web view using a visual state

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">

            <VisualState >
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" MinWindowHeight="0"  />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="webview.Width" Value="430"/>                                             
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState >
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1280" MinWindowHeight="720"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="webview.Width" Value="750"/>                       
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>


        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

What I want to do is give two font sizes to the web view similar to width.For now it is 25px for both laptop and PC screen.therefore in laptop screen content is cut off.If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate.Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if there is a way to trim the text in web view.I meant there is a property called TextTrimming in TextBlock control in uwp. likewise if there a control to trim the long texts in web view control then it can be used instead of changing font sizs.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> change font size in web view in uwp

You could use [`WebView.InvokeScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_InvokeScriptAsync_System_String_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__) method to inject `javascript` eval function and use the following  code to change the font side on the html page. For your scenario, you could listen the  `CoreWindow.SizeChanged` event and set the fontsize base on the window 's width.

For example:

```
 public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     MyWebView.DOMContentLoaded += MyWebView_DOMContentLoaded;
     Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += CoreWindow_SizeChanged;

 }

 private async void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
 {
     if (args.Size.Width == 1280 && isLoaded)
     {
         await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByTagName(\"div\")[0].style.fontSize=\"" + 30 + "\";" });
     }
 }

 private bool isLoaded;
 private void MyWebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
 {
     isLoaded = true;
 }
```